# program becomes very very slow

Tags: c++, qgis

I have a code was developed with qgis 1.8 and I have to do its update to version qgis 2.6, so there was a lot of function that are changed.

I would replace this instruction which is developped with qgis 1.8:

```
ptPolygonLayer->featureAtId ( tIntersectingFeatureId, tIntersectingFeature );
```

by a function that does the same thing with qgis 2.6 , so i found this function in the documentation qgis2.6

```
QgsFeatureIterator QgsVectorLayer::getFeatures  (   const QgsFeatureRequest &   request = QgsFeatureRequest()   )
```

and I adapted it to my code :

```
ptPolygonLayer->getFeatures ( QgsFeatureRequest( tIntersectingFeatureId)).nextFeature( tIntersectingFeature );
```

the problem that the program becomes very slow (it takes many hours) compared to the 1.8 version of qgis and I do not know why!!

I searched a lot but I have not found a solution that makes my program execute Normally.

Can you help me please. Thank you in advance

Comment: 1.) Have you checked, that the method call is the time killer, and not something that you do around? Print out (log) a timestamp before and after the getFeatures call. 2.) What about the context. Did you use an identical layer with data  from the same source?

Comment: Maybe the new library was not compiled with optimization options

Comment: have you seen [this page](https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Python_plugin_API_changes_from_18_to_20#QgsFeatureRequest-replaces-select-featureAtId)? It's in python, but you could adapt it to c++

Comment: thank you for your answers, yes I have already seen almost the same content in [http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html] ,and that is what I did, I even tried the suggestion of timestamp the execution of statement do not even have one second so there is not the problem. when I removed `nextFeature (tIntersectingFeature)`, the program does not crash, but I can not get the value of tIntersectingFeature which I need